# Pandas categorizing age variable into groups

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-loc

I have a dataframe df with age and I am working on categorizing the file into age groups with 0s and 1s.

df:

```
User_ID | Age
35435      22
45345      36
63456      18
63523      55
```

I tried the following

```
df['Age_GroupA'] = 0
df['Age_GroupA'][(df['Age'] >= 1) & (df['Age'] <= 25)] = 1
```

but get this error

```
SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
```

To avoid it, I am going for .loc

```
df['Age_GroupA'] = 0
df['Age_GroupA'] = df.loc[(df['Age'] >= 1) & (df['Age'] <= 25)] = 1
```

However, this marks all ages as 1

This is what I get

```
User_ID | Age | Age_GroupA
35435      22       1
45345      36       1
63456      18       1
63523      55       1
```

while this is the goal

```
User_ID | Age | Age_GroupA
35435      22       1
45345      36       0
63456      18       1
63523      55       0
```

Thank you

Comment: You want `df.loc[(df['Age_MDB_S'] >= 1) & (df['Age_MDB_S'] <= 25), 'Age_GroupA'] = 1`

Comment: this worked great @EdChum; can you please post it as an answer so I can accept it? thank you

Comment: @EdChum: come on, that's not a question or an aside, so it shouldn't be a comment.. ;-)

Comment: @DSM you make me feel guilty now ^_^;

Comment: it was quite an important question to me ....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to peer pressure (@DSM), I feel compelled to breakdown your error:

```
df['Age_GroupA'][(df['Age'] >= 1) & (df['Age'] <= 25)] = 1
```

this is [chained indexing/assignment](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy)

so what you tried next:

```
df['Age_GroupA'] = df.loc[(df['Age'] >= 1) & (df['Age'] <= 25)] = 1
```

is incorrect form, when using `loc` you want:

```
df.loc[<boolean mask>, cols of interest] = some scalar or calculated value
```

like this:

```
df.loc[(df['Age_MDB_S'] >= 1) & (df['Age_MDB_S'] <= 25), 'Age_GroupA'] = 1
```

You could also have done this using `np.where`:

```
df['Age_GroupA'] = np.where( (df['Age_MDB_S'] >= 1) & (df['Age_MDB_S'] <= 25), 1, 0)
```

To do this in 1 line, there are many ways to do this

Comment: Thank you - worked great; I think I got the doc logic down now

Comment: @jeangelj the subtle error here is that you had the mask in the middle portion to which you assign `1` but this chains to the lhs so all rows get assigned to 1

Comment: I see; I definitely see the advantage of loc over np.where and other methods; so thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

You can convert boolean mask to `int` - `True` are `1` and `False` are `0`:

```
df['Age_GroupA'] = ((df['Age'] >= 1) & (df['Age'] <= 25)).astype(int)
print (df)
   User ID        Age  Age_GroupA
0    35435         22           1
1    45345         36           0
2    63456         18           1
3    63523         55           0
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. Jezrael already explained it.

```
 dataframe['Age_GroupA'] = ((dataframe['Age'] >= 1) & (dataframe['Age'] <= 25)).astype(int)
```